# Auto increment number in pdf reports number

Tags: pdf, report, odoo

how to make the numbering for each pdf in odoo report?

[image]

Example: print report each added this "-001".
How to solve?

Comment: How do you print them?

Comment: Here you want page numbering or file name contain number?

Comment: solved. i find the solution. I use button action. /file name contain number/